# h20.ai JAVA REST API CLASS ISSUE with binomial prediction

Tags: java, r, machine-learning, deep-learning, h2o

I am using h2o binomial prediction and converting few string columns like this

```
X2 <- as.numeric(as.factor(test$X2))
X3 <- as.numeric(as.factor(test$X3))
X4 <- as.numeric(as.factor(test$X4))
```

and I generated h2o java pojo class for binomial model for Rest API call.

so, how do I convert my 2 string columns to required format in java. Since, the h2o team mentioned like all conversion should be done before h20 api call.

Comment: You should probably not use `as.numeric()` here.  You can have factor columns in your data and H2O will handle them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for how to use the POJO can be found here:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/index.html

The following example is taken from the documentation.  You can see that the RowData object contains the name and value for the new data point to predict on.  You can just pass in string values and the EasyPredictModelWrapper will convert them into something the model knows how to use.

```
String modelClassName = "your_pojo_model_class_name";
hex.genmodel.GenModel rawModel;
rawModel = (hex.genmodel.GenModel) Class.forName(modelClassName).newInstance();
EasyPredictModelWrapper model = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(rawModel);

RowData row = new RowData();
row.put("Year", "1987");
row.put("Month", "10");
row.put("DayofMonth", "14");
row.put("DayOfWeek", "3");
row.put("CRSDepTime", "730");
row.put("UniqueCarrier", "PS");
row.put("Origin", "SAN");
row.put("Dest", "SFO");

BinomialModelPrediction p = model.predictBinomial(row);
```

Comment: I am trying to connect with web app and jquery just followed by this tutorial        https://github.com/h2oai/app-consumer-loan , but rest api connection and h2o everything is running, but all the time the curl command return the same result as json, so how do i fix that ?? but the prediction is working well using h2o in R studio, but not in curl command..please help

Comment: Since the app-consumer-loan example works properly, one thing you can do is use 'git diff' to examine all the differences between the original version and your modified version.  One of the changes you made is causing it not to work.  Try making the smallest possible change, one at a time, from the original to see where you are getting off track.